# PHP executing (python) is not working when importing to python

Tags: php, python, exec, nltk, ipc

When trying to execute a python code from php by using

```
echo  shell_exec('python search.py "'.$a.'" "'.$b.'"');
```

the python script is outping $a and $b when only sys is imported

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys
    sys.stderr = sys.stdout
    a = sys.argv[1]
    b = sys.argv[2] 
    print a+" && "+b
```

but when I try to import something else such as Numpy, the php return nothing:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from nltk import word_tokenize
    sys.stderr = sys.stdout
    a = sys.argv[1]
    b = sys.argv[2] 
    print a+" && "+b
```

i try running it from the machine itself (from ssh) and from it everything is working just fine..

already tried looking into some question here on stackoverflow and other places but nothing seems to work for me..

I'm running Debian and using python2.7

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "search.py", line 5, in from nltk.corpus import stopwords File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 137, in from nltk.stem import * File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/__init__.py", line 29, in from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/snowball.py", line 26, in from nltk.corpus import stopwords File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/__init__.py", line 66, in from nltk.corpus.reader import * File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/__init__.py", line 105, in from nltk.corpus.reader.panlex_lite import * File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/panlex_lite.py", line 15, in import sqlite3 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in from dbapi2 import * File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in from _sqlite3 import * ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

Thanks for the help!

Solved!
Should have specify the folder of Python in the PHP
And to add import cgi, cgitb to the Pythonn

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the whole path to echo command. Something like:

```
echo  shell_exec('usr/bin/doc/python search.py "'.$a.'" "'.$b.'"');
```

thanks, aditya